# Running python scripts against the subscription

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure

I have a azure subscription , I want to list all my storage accounts my subscription contains.

I have downloaded the code from https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python. I am trying to run the downloaded code in ubuntu 12.04 machine.

There is a file called test_storagemanagementservice.py in the repo which contains the method to return the storage accounts , but there is no relevant information readme file like how to run the python script,I am not able to figure this out exactly as I am relatively new to python coding.

When I try to run  $python -m unittest discover -p "tests.test_storagemanagementservice.py" , I am just getting message "0 tests run". Any idea to run this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve beyond listing your storage accounts? Do you just want to see the code run or would you actually like to add this to a Django site?

Comment: I want to see the code run from this repo only , and I want to list ,storage accounts ,get storage keys , list db etc operations ... but against this repo only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is ,

download the repo and place it in a drive for eg: d:\azure-sdk-for-python

Then later use these sample programs, and execute the sample programs to check if the service is working , for eg: cloud service, storage service etc.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management/